# API.ai looping on purpose

Tags: javascript, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have my API.ai getting an answer from the user and sending it to a JS webhook, in which I check whether their answer is correct. I want to make it so that if they get the answer wrong it'll ask repeatedly until they get it right. How would I achieve this, can I set an output context in my webhook if the user answer fails the comparison (which doesn't activate if they get it correct)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kkofje5b/2/) as a template.  The actual implementation details for retrieving result and requesting server if result is okay are contained respectively in the functions `getAnswer` and `checkResultOK`.

The use of a callback in checkResultOK makes it possible for checkResultOK to work asynchronously (in this case trivially so by adding a slight delay).

You could also use Promises if you prefer, but you'll need a library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).